# How to use webfont NPM?

Tags: node.js, webfonts

```
//app.js            
const webfont = require('webfont').default;

webfont({
    fontName: 'myfont',
    files: './src/*.ttf',
    formats: ['woff','eot']
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

## run

node app.js

error：
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Files glob patterns specified did not match any files.

Answer (score 0):

From the sourcecode:

```
var filteredFiles = foundFiles.filter(function (foundFile) {
            return _path2.default.extname(foundFile) === '.svg';
        });

        if (filteredFiles.length === 0) {
            throw new Error('Files glob patterns specified did not match any files');
        }
```

So unfortunately you can only convert from svg. You would have to change the source.